# Passing parameter from AJAX to DJANGO

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I want to pass a parameter from javascript into the django views using window.location. In this case the variable 'query' which is the string 'hi'. How would I go about doing this? Below is what isn't working :) yet everything works fine when I try without a parameter. Help?

views.py

```
def error(request, query):
    print(query)
    return render(request, 'error.html')
```

html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#butt").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: 'profile',
            datatype:'json',
            data: {
                'profname': 'jilsmith',
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.status == 0){ 
                    alert("error page");

                    var query = "hi";
                    window.location = data.url(query);
                }
                if(data.status == 1){ 
                    alert("profile page");
                    window.location = data.profile
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable on de DATA section from Ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#butt").click(function(){
var query = "hi";
           $.ajax({
           type: "get",
           url: 'profile',
           datatype:'json',
            data: {query: query, profname: 'jilsmith'},
              success: function(data) {
                if(data.status == 0){ 
             alert("error page");

             window.location = data.url(query);

             }
              if(data.status == 1){ 
             alert("profile page");
             window.location = data.profile
             }
           }

       }); 
  });
});
```

Comment: If I remove the parameter, everything works fine. It's only when I try to pass it to the views that I get an error. FYI: I am not trying to put the variable in the actual URL. I need it to get information for the page im rendering.